# Robot Framework variable attribute in seperate file not storing attribute to be used elsewhere

Tags: selenium, testing, robotframework

Variable attribute not getting passed into other file.

I have my variables for element locators stored in one file and I have assertions done in another file which has worked fine until now and separates things out nicely. I am doing an assertion to check that an element exists and its attribute(value) is not blank. If I write it on one page as follows it works perfectly. This use the selenium library keywords `should not be equal` and `Get Element Attribute` just to note.

```
${EXAMPLE}  get element attribute  class=test test-data
should not be equal  ${EXAMPLE}  ${EMPTY}
```

But If I separate them out into different files. So a locators.robot file:

```
 #Locater File
 ${EXAMPLE}  get element attribute  class=test[test-data]
```

And an Assertions.robot:

```
 #Assertion File
 should not be equal  ${EXAMPLE}  ${EMPTY}
```

It stops working. If I use a selenium library assertion like `page should contain element` then it works, so I know I am pulling in the other Resource correctly. I have a feeling I may need to store the attribute in another variable somehow and actually assert against that. Any ideas would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such keyword in SeleniumLibrary as `get data attribute` you mean the `Get Element Attribute` keyword?  http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute Which version of SeleniumLibrary do you use? Also please share more of your locator.robot and Asertions.robot files, hard to find out what is this `${EXAMPLE}  get data attribute  class=test[test-data]` in your locator.robot file. Is it part of a keyword, or is it a variable?

Comment: @BenceKaulics Sorry, I mistyped, you are correct it is Get Element Attribute. ${EXAMPLE} is the Variable name for the locator I want to find. I want to assert it exists and also that its value is not empty. Hence the `should not be equal  ${EXAMPLE}  ${EMPTY}`. i.e. the elements value should contain something and not be empty.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct it and please add whole variable table from the locators.robot and also the whole keyword or test case code from the Asertions.robot. I have guesses what can be wrong but not for sure, not until we see more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have html code like this as you given in other question -

```
<div id="top-list">
<div data-version="12345" data-list="1"  data-point="10">
```

**Way 1** - *Less recommended* -
This is how my `assertion.robot` looks like -

```
*Settings  
Library         SeleniumLibrary  
Resource        Locator.robot


*Test Cases

Test attributes Locator

    Open Browser        file:///C:Desktop/testxpath.html          chrome
    ${attribute_value}=      Get Element attribute    ${Datalist_locator_with_all_attribt}    data-list
    should not be equal     ${attribute_value}     ${EMPTY}
```

The locators are in `locator.robot` file. I'm not calling `Get Element Attribute` keyword in the locators because doing so there will be no link of directly executing it and referencing back the return value of it in testcase... So just keeping the locators in the locator file nothing else. This locators are accessible when I did `Resource        Locator.robot` in my `assertion.robot` file. As you can see the `Get Element Attribute` element take first argument locator of element and second argument is nothing but the attribute name of which value you need. And this keyword returns value of attribute that supplied as second argument. -

```
*Variables

${Datalist_locator_with_all_attribt}         xpath://div[@data-version='12345' and @data-list='1' and @data-point='10']
${locator_with_single_attribute}            xpath://div[@data-version='12345']
```

**Output**

[image]

**Way 2** - *More Recommended* -
Wrap the `Get Element Attribute` and `Should Not Be Equal` keywords in one single keyword. and dump it in another keyword file or create `*keywords` section in `locator.robot` file itself. Doing this your `assertion.robot` file will look like this -

```
*Test Cases

Test attributes Locator

    Open Browser        file:///C:/Desktop/testxpath.html         chrome
    Attribute values should not be empty
```

and `locator.robot` will look like this. You can make it more generic though -

```
*** Variables

${Datalist_locator_with_all_attribt}         xpath://div[@data-version='12345' and @data-list='1' and @data-point='10']
${locator_with_single_attribute}            xpath://div[@data-version='12345']

*** Keywords

Attribute values should not be empty

    ${attribute_value}=      Get Element attribute    ${Datalist_locator_with_all_attribt}    data-list
    should not be equal     ${attribute_value}     ${EMPTY}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dev. You explained that all very well. Both ways work. I suppose I need to figure out now which one works best for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Also if you pay close attention on locators. and if you don't need values of attributes other than this case you simply can assert the locator exist on page no need of attributes. Just put all attributes in locator of the element.